# Laravel relationship not working. Relationship method is not getting called

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make rest api. I have following database tables

```
products:
id, title, cat_id

cats:
id, name
```

Product Model:

```
public function cat(){
   return $this->hasOne('App\Cat');
}
```

Cat model

```
public function products(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

when I try to access product, following is returned:

```
{"id": 1,
"title": "Example",
"cat_id": 1}
```

I want this to be

```
{"id": 1,
"title": "Example",
"cat": {
       "id": 1,
        "name": "Ex"
      }
}
```

what am I doing wrong here. please help

Comment: How do you access your product ? you can try with your eloquent model `Product::find($id)->with('cat')->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vincent mentioned you probably want to eager load the Cat model when loading a Product model. Eager loading is described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) in the Laravel docs. So running

```php
Product::find($id)->with('cat')->get();
```

will load the product for the given `$id` and automatically query the Cat relationship as well.

Answer (score 2):

`HasOne` is not the right relationship here. The inverse of `HasMany` is `BelongsTo`:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function cat()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Cat');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what the exact domain for the issue Mandip is trying to solve, but it's perfectly fine to have a relationship in which one side can have any, but the other side just has one. In this case it would mean that 1 product is always for 1 cat, but 1 cat have multiple products

Comment: Yes, but `HasOne` isn't meant for that. You *can* use it, but only with custom keys.